# How to perform a line break?

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown

I entered text with line breaks in the body but it doesn't show in the question.

Comment: Two line breaks is a paragraph break, two spaces at the end of the line cause a line break without a paragraph break. See also [help/formatting](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: See also: [How to start new line on MSE?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17656)

Comment: I have noticed that you included ([meta-tag:mathjax]) tag - so you want to ask how to make a line break *in the math mode?* If you are asking about regular text (not formulas) then ([meta-tag:markdown]) is a more suitable tag and the links given in the previous comments should give you an answer to this.

Answer (score 4):

Line break within math mode.
`$$
x + y = 2\\x - y = 4
$$`
Output:
$$
x + y = 2\\x - y = 4
$$

Comment: And in anticipation of the obvious followup question about aligning the multiple lines, [see this section of the tutorial/quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5024/5676).

Answer (score 3):

Input: [image]
Output:

Period.
Period.
Period and two spaces.
Period.
Period.
Period.

Period.
Period.